# Replace given <img> source

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-weather-api

I made a plugin with Google Weather API and I am currently pulling the images from Google's API. For a sunny day I'm pulling `http://www.google.com//ig/images/weather/sunny.gif`.

I am looking for a way so that when ever sunny.gif is pulled, replace with with an image of my choice.

Is that possible with jQuery or other way?

Thanks alot

Comment: How are you retrieving the data?

Comment: I might re-tag your question then to be PHP rather than javascript and jQuery.. You'll want to edit that data server-side rather than client-side.

Comment: This is where I'm pulling off: http://www.google.co.uk/ig/api?weather=london ... You think it better to do it in PHP an set, when img = sunny.gif, show customsunny.gif or something?

Comment: If you're replacing a string that you've received from a data source server side, then yes. It's always better to do the replace there. Having it in the client side means that you might get a flicker (unless you're handling it) and worst case, you have an unneeded server request.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$("#my_image").attr("src","http://www.myimagepath.com/image.jpg");
```

Comment: I thought of that sir, but every day has the same class. It's not possible to set each day a different class or ID.

Comment: like you have a 7 day forecast and you want to know images for each day?

Answer (score 5):

Depends on how you're receiving/passing the image, just set it to a variable and check for it.
This is the easy/lazy solution to this simple problem, if your problem is more complex you could turn this into a function that checks and replaces sunny, stormy, etc...

```
if (img === "http://www.google.com//ig/images/weather/sunny.gif") {
  img = "myownimage.gif";
}
```

PHP/JS anti-pattern:

```
<?php if ($image === "http://www.google.com//ig/images/weather/sunny.gif"): ?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#image").attr('src', 'foo.gif');
  </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But honestly if you're receiving the image in PHP, then I'd just manipulate it server-side and display it to the client then rather than have JavaScript do it...

```
<?php
if ($image === "http://www.google.com//ig/images/weather/sunny.gif") {
  $image = 'foo.gif';
}
?>

<img src="<?php echo $image ?>" alt="my sunny day image" />
```

Comment: Something likes is what I was looking for. Can you set a class instead. Like: If ($('.day img') img == "http://www.google.com//ig/images/weather/sunny.gif") {} ???

Comment: You can set a class if in your css you are setting your image as a background image.

Comment: Not possible, every day has the same class with different background image.

Comment: that's fine. in JavaScript you can pull the src of an image and just check for sunny/rainy/cloudy/etc... document.getElementById('image').src will give you it's src, then you can just use the function `indexOf` to determine if it's sunny or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

There is a live [document.images](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-90379117) collection of all img elements in the document. You can conditionally change the src property of any particular image based on whatever logic you like:

```
var image, images = document.images;

for (var i=0, iLen=images.length; i<iLen; i++) {
  image = images[i];
  if (image.src == 'whatever') image.src = 'new value';
}
```

You may want to access the image's *parentNode* and some of its properties too.

But is seems to me that this is much better done on the server.